# Read File in GWT server side

Tags: java, gwt, io

I need to read a properties file in the server-side of a GWT application.

I've tried to put the file in the root of the application and into the src folder. However, in both tries, A `FileNotFound` exception is thrown.

I create the file using the following code:

```
File file = new File("errors.properties");
```

Is it wrong? Where should I put the file?

Comment: What server are you running?  Is your server-side component also in Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

into your `war` folder. I suppose you use Eclipse and integrated Google plugin to generate the app and also to run it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the properties in your server side code and then send it to your GWT code. See [this](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/clientserver.html) page for server-client communication. The file itself should probably be in your war folder. Also you cannot use `File` in your GWT code as it is not a supported emulated JRE library class. See [here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html#Package_java_io) for supported library classes available in GWT.